# Deadlock using SELECT ... FOR UPDATE in MySQL

Tags: mysql

Let's say I have the table:

```
CREATE TABLE t (id INTEGER AUTOINCREMENT NOT NULL, desc TEXT NOT NULL)
```

I populate the table with 1 element:

```
INSERT INTO TABLE t VALUES (1, 'Hello')
```

And I run two transactions in MySQL. In `t1` I run:

```
START TRANSACTION;
SELECT * FROM t WHERE id = 1 FOR UPDATE;
```

In `t2` I run:

```
START TRANSACTION;
SELECT * FROM t WHERE id = 1 FOR UPDATE;
```

At this point I expect `t1` to hold an e(X)clusive lock on the row, and `t2` to wait until it can get an X lock (and `t2` gets indeed blocked, so far so good). I then run an update in `t1` (without any WHERE clause!):

```
UPDATE t SET desc = 'Hello from t1';
```

At this point in `t2` I get immediately (no need to `COMMIT` the transaction) the error:

```
ERROR 1213 (40001): Deadlock found when trying to get lock; try restarting transaction
```

Why am I getting this error? I guess there is a lock that `t2` is obtaining that the full UPDATE needs to proceed, making a deadlock, but I don't understand how can `t2` obtain a lock given that it should be waiting for `t1` to finish.

Comment: I cannot reproduce this with 5.5.27 (running on Windows)- to me this sounds like a bug.

Comment: What version are you using?

Comment: MySQL version 5.5.35

Answer (score 10, accepted):

## What works and what does not

A way to make both transactions run through without a deadlock is to change the [isolation level](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/set-transaction.html) to *READ COMMITED* (or *READ UNCOMMITED*) in both connections:

```
SET SESSION TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL READ COMMITTED;
```

(before `start transaction`).

Likely it would be enough to set it in `t2`, but just to be sure for the example, set it in both.

Changing the isolation level of transactions does introduce some side-effects, which one should inform about [in the manual](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/set-transaction.html) before changing this in a production environment.

## Status information concerning deadlock

```
------------------------
LATEST DETECTED DEADLOCK
------------------------
140424  8:45:46
*** (1) TRANSACTION:
TRANSACTION B6F18A3, ACTIVE 5 sec starting index read
mysql tables in use 1, locked 1
LOCK WAIT 2 lock struct(s), heap size 376, 1 row lock(s)
MySQL thread id 13885, OS thread handle 0x7f8b1dbd2700, query id 901012
 localhost root statistics
SELECT * FROM t WHERE id = 1 FOR UPDATE
*** (1) WAITING FOR THIS LOCK TO BE GRANTED:
RECORD LOCKS space id 0 page no 22921 n bits 72 index `PRIMARY` of table
 `test`.`t` trx id B6F18A3 lock_mode X locks rec but not gap waiting
Record lock, heap no 4 PHYSICAL RECORD: n_fields 4; compact format; info bits 0
 0: len 4; hex 80000001; asc     ;;
 1: len 6; hex 00000b6f1883; asc    o  ;;
 2: len 7; hex 06000059a211ea; asc    Y   ;;
 3: len 5; hex 48656c6c6f; asc Hello;;

*** (2) TRANSACTION:
TRANSACTION B6F18A2, ACTIVE 10 sec starting index read
mysql tables in use 1, locked 1
3 lock struct(s), heap size 376, 2 row lock(s)
MySQL thread id 13888, OS thread handle 0x7f8b1f64d700, query id 901068
 localhost root Updating
UPDATE t SET `descc` = 'Hello from t1'
*** (2) HOLDS THE LOCK(S):
RECORD LOCKS space id 0 page no 22921 n bits 72 index `PRIMARY` of table
 `test`.`t` trx id B6F18A2 lock_mode X locks rec but not gap
Record lock, heap no 4 PHYSICAL RECORD: n_fields 4; compact format; info bits 0
 0: len 4; hex 80000001; asc     ;;
 1: len 6; hex 00000b6f1883; asc    o  ;;
 2: len 7; hex 06000059a211ea; asc    Y   ;;
 3: len 5; hex 48656c6c6f; asc Hello;;

*** (2) WAITING FOR THIS LOCK TO BE GRANTED:
RECORD LOCKS space id 0 page no 22921 n bits 72 index `PRIMARY` of table
 `test`.`t` trx id B6F18A2 lock_mode X waiting
Record lock, heap no 4 PHYSICAL RECORD: n_fields 4; compact format; info bits 0
 0: len 4; hex 80000001; asc     ;;
 1: len 6; hex 00000b6f1883; asc    o  ;;
 2: len 7; hex 06000059a211ea; asc    Y   ;;
 3: len 5; hex 48656c6c6f; asc Hello;;

*** WE ROLL BACK TRANSACTION (1)
```

## Explanation

As a_horse_with_no_name mentioned, this seems like a bug in MySQL. Transaction (2) wants to obtain a gap lock on the same row it already holds an X lock. Transaction (1) waits for a non-gap X lock on this row. It is not clear to me why this requests should conflict. Setting the isolation level to `READ COMMITTED` disables gap locking. Since the example works then, this is a hint that gap locking is indeed the problem here.

Comment: The isolation level (at least a "real" transactional - which `read uncommitted` is not) should not make a difference. The `update` without in T1 does not touch any row that wasn't already locked and the waiting T2 does not wait for any other row. So there is absolutely no reason why a deadlock should occur. From my point of view this is a bug in MySQL

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name I use 5.5.35-0+wheezy1-log. I updated my answer, showing also the status output. On the closer second look I agree with you, that this seems like a bug. Although I wonder why you cannot reproduce the error with an older version of MySQL?

Comment: @GhostGambler I think the "What works and what does not" section in your answer should be limited to say that this bug can be workaround using the READ COMMITTED or READ UNCOMMITTED isolation level, if the user can deal with this isolation on those transactions. If you edit your answer I will accept it. I logged a bug about this in mysql (http://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=72439)

Comment: @JoaquinCuencaAbela I shortened the section and added a notice that one should not change the isolation level without reading the manual thoroughly.

Comment: I can confirm that the deadlock occurs on MySQL 5.7 if you are using Isolation Serializable. Changing to Read Commited the deadlock error is gone. Great answer, btw.

Comment: According to https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/innodb-locking.html#innodb-intention-locks, IX locks are compatible with other IX locks (IX locks are what you get with a SELECT FOR UPDATE). That seems like this behavior is intentional, although I have no idea WHY.

Comment: @Thayne Your referenced table is for table-level locks. Intention locks are only relevant for full table operations (`Intention locks do not block anything except full table requests (for example, LOCK TABLES ... WRITE).`). Instead, the question is why a gap lock request conflicts with a waiting record X lock. I do not see that answered in the documentation. But I updated the last paragraph of my answer to pose this question better.