# Mysql deadlock on "SELECT ... FOR UPDATE" and insert

Tags: mysql, multithreading, locking, deadlock, isolation-level

I am receiving deadlocks when running this piece of code below.

The purpose of the code is to insert a new Title into the Title table with the end result being that I need to set the defaultTitle bit if no other title has the defaultTitle bit set already.

The Title Table is foreign keyed to the Product Table (thus there is a non unique index on ProductId). The Title table looks like this:

```
CREATE TABLE `Title` (
  `ID` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `ProductId` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `Title` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `DefaultBit` bit(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT b'0',
  PRIMARY KEY (`ID`),
  KEY `fk_product_Title` (`ProductId`),
  CONSTRAINT `title_fk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`ProductId`) REFERENCES `product` (`ID`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

In this example transaction I want to add 2 new titles to the Title table for the same product. If I run this code in 2 different sessions at the same time, it always deadlocks.

The outcome I want is for there to be no deadlock, the first transaction sets DefaultBit to 1, the second sets DefaultBit to 0.

```
START TRANSACTION;

SET @prodId = 4;

SET @insTitleDefault = (SELECT  IF(COUNT(PT.ID) > 0, 0, 1) as defaultOrNot
FROM    ProductTitle PT
WHERE   PT.ProductId = @prodId);

SELECT SLEEP(2); - Added for testing to pinpoint the deadlock.

INSERT INTO Title
(`ProductId`,`Title`,`DefaultBit`)
VALUES
(@prodId ,"Some title text",@insTitleDefault);

SET @newTitleId = LAST_INSERT_ID();

SELECT * FROM Title WHERE ProductId = @prodId;

-- COMMIT; -- commenting out the commit for testing purposes, Rollback instead
ROLLBACK;
```

I have tried to add FOR UPDATE

```
SET @insTitleDefault = (SELECT  IF(COUNT(PT.ID) > 0, 0, 1) as defaultOrNot
FROM    ProductTitle PT
WHERE   PT.ProductId = @prodId FOR UPDATE);
```

But this does not work either and still deadlocks.

I have also tried to run the entire transaction in different Isolation Modes as per answer in [Deadlock using SELECT ... FOR UPDATE in MySQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21851119/deadlock-using-select-for-update-in-mysql)

```
SET SESSION TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL READ COMMITTED;
```

This does not cause deadlocks but it also does not preserve the correct DefaultBit as it sets both transactions values to 1 (and there should only be 1 default per product).

---

### My analysis so far:

I have run show ENGINE INNODB status; after each deadlock and get the following relevant info:

```
LATEST DETECTED DEADLOCK
------------------------
2015-07-30 10:05:18 3808
*** (1) TRANSACTION:
TRANSACTION 227273, ACTIVE 6 sec inserting
mysql tables in use 2, locked 2
LOCK WAIT 6 lock struct(s), heap size 1184, 3 row lock(s), undo log entries 1
MySQL thread id 93, OS thread handle 0x433c, query id 3098292 localhost 127.0.0.1 user update
INSERT INTO Title(`ProductId`,`Title`,`DefaultBit`)
VALUES(@pId,"Some title text",@insTitleDefault)
*** (1) WAITING FOR THIS LOCK TO BE GRANTED:
RECORD LOCKS space id 380 page no 132 n bits 752 index `fk_product_Title` of table `globalhq`.`Title` trx id 227273 lock_mode X insert intention waiting
Record lock, heap no 1 PHYSICAL RECORD: n_fields 1; compact format; info bits 0
 0: len 8; hex 73757072656d756d; asc supremum;;

*** (2) TRANSACTION:
TRANSACTION 227274, ACTIVE 4 sec inserting, thread declared inside InnoDB 5000
mysql tables in use 2, locked 2
6 lock struct(s), heap size 1184, 3 row lock(s), undo log entries 1
MySQL thread id 95, OS thread handle 0x3808, query id 3098300 localhost 127.0.0.1 user update
INSERT INTO Title(`ProductId`,`Title`,`DefaultBit`)
VALUES(@pId,"Some title text",@insTitleDefault)
*** (2) HOLDS THE LOCK(S):
RECORD LOCKS space id 380 page no 132 n bits 752 index `fk_product_Title` of table `globalhq`.`Title` trx id 227274 lock mode S
Record lock, heap no 1 PHYSICAL RECORD: n_fields 1; compact format; info bits 0
 0: len 8; hex 73757072656d756d; asc supremum;;

*** (2) WAITING FOR THIS LOCK TO BE GRANTED:
RECORD LOCKS space id 380 page no 132 n bits 752 index `fk_product_Title` of table `globalhq`.`Title` trx id 227274 lock_mode X insert intention waiting
Record lock, heap no 1 PHYSICAL RECORD: n_fields 1; compact format; info bits 0
 0: len 8; hex 73757072656d756d; asc supremum;;

*** WE ROLL BACK TRANSACTION (2)
```

I gather This is what is happening

1. TX1 is putting a S lock on the select statement
2. TX2 is also putting a S lock on the select statement
3. TX1 puts the IX lock on the Insert statement but is blocked from point 2
4. TX2 puts the IX lock on the Insert statement but is blocked from point 2 and 3, hence the deadlock on TX 2.

When I add a FOR UPDATE to the select statement:

1. TX1 is putting a IX lock on the select statement
2. TX2 is also putting a IX lock on the select statement
3. TX1 puts the X lock on the Insert statement but is blocked from point 2
4. TX2 puts the X lock on the Insert statement but is blocked from point 2 and 3, hence the deadlock on TX 2.

I am not sure of the correct way forward as every method I have tried has left the procedure open to deadlocks. Any suggestions would be awesome.

Answer (score 0):

**i suggest you to add an index on "PT.ProductId" column .**
i had the same issue and solve like above.
The principle is when an index exists , 'select for update' will lock the index, other 'select for update' or 'insert' of other transactions will be blocked until the first transaction committed. so deadlock will not happen.