# Concurrent getting tasks from MySQL table

Tags: php, mysql, transactions, deadlock

I have a lot of console applications that perform different tasks. I getting unique task from php script:

```
$mysqli->autocommit(FALSE);
$result = $mysqli->query("SELECT id, task FROM queue WHERE locked = 0 LIMIT 1 FOR UPDATE;");

while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()){ 
    $mysqli->query('UPDATE queue SET locked = 1 WHERE id="'.$row['id'].'";');
    $mysqli->commit();
    $response["response"]["task"] = $row["task"];
}

$mysqli->close();   
echo json_encode($response);
```

Sometimes I have duplicate task and, "Deadlock found when trying to get lock; try restarting transaction".
What am I doing wrong?

UPD: set index on "locked" column solve problem

Comment: Don't think it's related to the error, but why are you using a `while` loop when you specify `LIMIT 1`? It can never return more than one row, so you don't need to loop.

Comment: Do you have an index on the `locked` column? Try adding it.

Comment: Your application should handle such errors according to http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/innodb-deadlocks-handling.html and then resubmit, in case of an error. Setting an index, and keeping the transactions small can minimize the deadlock risk.

Comment: This code makes no sense! You set up to run a transaction and then commit after each update?? You Select using `LIMIT 1` and then while loop over a single result??

Comment: Is this code also in an outer while loop?

Comment: @Barmar seems index solved this problem, thx :)

Comment: @RiggsFolly Since it's at most a single row, the `while` is effectively an `if`.

Comment: I've seen hundreds of questions here where people use `while` to process the result of a query, even though it can only return 1 row, simply because that's the pattern they're used to. Newbie programmers don't design based on logic, they just copy what they've seen or written before without thinking about it.

Comment: @Barmar I agree. Thats no reason not to point out that it is unnecessary/illogical though in my opinion

Comment: @RiggsFolly I know, did you read my first comment where I pointed out the same folly?

Comment: Maybe this question is also relevant: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21851119/deadlock-using-select-for-update-in-mysql/23244630#23244630

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the MySQL documentation [How to Minimize and Handle Deadlocks](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/innodb-deadlocks-handling.html):

> Add well-chosen indexes to your tables. Then your queries need to scan fewer index records and consequently set fewer locks.

Adding an index to the `locked` column should solve this. Without it, the `SELECT` query has to scan through the table, looking for a row with `locked = 0`, and all the rows it steps through must be locked.

If you add an index to the column in the `WHERE` clause, it can go directly to that record and lock it. No other records are locked, so the possibility of deadlock is reduced.